# What is the best way to deploying a web-scrapping app

Tags: web-scraping, puppeteer, hosting, nodemailer, node-cron

I have just finished making a web-scraper which emails me my classes with Nodemailer and node-cron. How could I deploy it so that it runs while my computer is off? It should send me about 4 emails a day before each class. Any Help would be great thanks :)

I have looked into Vps but am a but stuck and don't know if thats what i should use or how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

In order to run programs while your computer is off, you obviously need to run those programs from a running computer.

You can use a [VPS](https://cloud.google.com/learn/what-is-a-virtual-private-server) - your private server that is always on (if you wish).

Or, you can use any of the hosting services, most of which have some kind of a free tier, like Github Actions.